# Python 3: My decorated function runs twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have some simple fibonacci sequence functions that I am practicing unit testing and builds with Travis-CI/Docker:

fib_recursive.py:

```
from fib.fib import benchmark, fib_rec_memo

@benchmark
def print_fib(n):
    for x in range(0, n):
        print(fib_rec_memo(x))

print_fib(100)
```

here is the fib.fib import source code:

```
from time import time
from functools import wraps

def benchmark(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t = time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(func.__name__, 'took:', time() - t)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def fib_rec_memo(n, hash = {0:1, 1:1}):
    if n not in hash:
        hash[n] = fib_rec_memo(n-1) + fib_rec_memo(n-2)
    return hash[n]


@benchmark
def fib_standard(num):
    a, b = 0, 1
    c = []
    while a < num:            # First iteration:
        c.append(a)            # yield 0 to start with and then
        a, b = b, a + b    # a will now be 1, and b will also be 1, (0 + 1)
    return c
```

For some reason executing python3 ./fib_recursive.py launches the function twice:

```
# python3 ./fib_recursive.py
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
print_fib took: 0.00011181831359863281
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
#
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: *"for some reason"* - because you literally call it twice?

Answer (score 7):

You are calling the decorated function twice in the `wrapper` function:

```
func(*args, **kwargs)  # here ...
print(func.__name__, 'took:', time() - t)
return func(*args, **kwargs)  # ... and here again
```

You can avoid that by storing the result to a variable and returning that stored result after your timing output:

```
rval = func(*args, **kwargs)  # call it once and store result ...
print(func.__name__, 'took:', time() - t)
return rval  # ... then return result
```